# Command line qustion

Tags: command-line

What is the difference between these two commands?

```
$ cat volcanoes.txt | wc > islands.txt
```

results:

```
$ cat islands.txt                                                             
17      26     204
```

second command:

```
$ cat volcanoes.txt | wc | cat > islands.txt
```

results:

```
$ cat islands.txt                                                             
17      26     204
```

We can see two results are same.
I am confused about the second commands.Why it has another cat in the commands.

Thank you for the help:)

Comment: Here’s a third, this with no `cat`s: `wc < volcanoes.txt > islands.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cat` command just copies its input to its output verbatim.

So even

`cat volcanoes.txt | cat | cat | wc | cat | cat | cat | cat > islands.txt`

would lead to the same content of islands.txt.

Even without cat you can get the same result:

`wc < volcanoes.txt > islands.txt`

This one being the most efficient version, starting only one process.